# Restrict mapping to existing destination objects

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, automapper, nullable-reference-types

I have a project using AutoMapper and Entity Framework Core that I've just upgraded to use C#8's new nullable reference types ([Nullable Reference Types @ .NET Conf 2019](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TJiLhRPgyq4&list=PLReL099Y5nRd04p81Q7p5TtyjCrj9tz1t&index=5&t=0s)).

Following the advice from Microsoft for [using nullable reference types with EF Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/nullable-reference-types), I created constructors for my entity classes with parameters for my required properties to ensure they cannot be null.

I have the following entity type and a patch type used when I want to update the entity's description:

```cs
public class DocType {
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int? SortIndex { get; set;}

    // I added this after the C#8 upgrade
    public DocType(string code, string description) {
        Code = code;
        Description = description;
    }
}

public class ModifyDocTypePatch {
    public string? Description { get; set; }
    public int SortIndex { get; set; }
}
```

Now I need to be able to map a `DocType` to a `ModifyDocTypePatch` and back. The caveat is that when mapping back to a `DocType` I should only be allowed to map to an existing `DocType`, not create a new one.

Before my upgrade I had this mapping profile:

```cs
public class DocTypeProfile : Profile {
    public DocTypeProfile() {
        CreateMap<DocType, ModifyDocType>()
            .ReverseMap();
    }
}
```

This worked fine, but after adding the constructor it doesn't. AutoMapper requires a parameterless constructor. I thought I could use the `.ConstructUsing()` method to tell automapper to use the new constructor when mapping back from a `ModifyDocTypePatch`, but that doesn't work because the constructor requires a code, and the patch doesn't have one.

Is there a way to create a mapping that only applies to existing destination objects? So that I could do:

```cs
var docType = new DocType("code", "description");
var patch = new ModifyDocTypePatch { Description = "new description" };
var mapped = _mapper.Map(patch, docType);
```

but not:

```cs
var patch = new ModifyDocTypePatch { Description = "new description" };
var mapped = _mapper.Map<ModifyDocTypePatch, DocType>(patch);
```

#### Update

Thanks to the tip from Lucian, I was able to come up with a work-around.
I added a private parameterless constructor to `DocType`. This seemed to satisfy AutoMappers constructor requirements. I also added `DisableConstructorMapping()` to my Profile because the new (parameterized) constructor was causing some properties to be mapped that I had marked should be ignored.

While this is workable, what I don't like about it is the need to change my domain models just to accommodate AutoMapper. If someone has a better solution, I'd love to hear it!

Comment: http://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Construction.html